# How to add to a list in a JSON value?

Tags: python, json

This might be a duplicate question, however, I wasn't able to find a solution to my own problem. I have this file called d.json. It holds, IDs and Names, it's test file.

```
{
    "id": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ],
    "name": "p"
}
```

^ That is the current JSON. I need to be able to edit that ID list, however, I have tried this solution:

```
>>> with open('d.json', 'r+') as f:
       data = json.load(f)
       r = data['id'].append("3")
       f.write(r)
       f.close()
```

However, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 4, in <module>
    f.write(r)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

The whole idea is for me to be able to open the JSON file, add a quick value to the list, close it, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn your json to string before writing it back to the file. Try this:

```
with open('d.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['id'].append("3")
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, f)
    f.truncate()
```